# How to set a view height to be equal to its width

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, autolayout

I created a UIView, then I added a constrain on the uiview that its width is equal to its superview width. Then I want to make this uiview's height to be equal to it's width. I don't know how to add this kind of constrain. I can see that I can add a height constrain on this view but how to set its value to be equal to its width?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Add the Aspect Ratio constraint to your view[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can set a view height to be equal to its width either from `storyboard` or `programmatically` for this you need to add the `aspect ratio` constraint on a view with multiplier 1.

**From storyboard** you can add the `aspect ratio` constraint with the help of [Pin Tools](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_auto_layout/chapters/pin-constraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014226-CH28-SW1) in storyboard

**By programmatically** you can try below code, It is working fine.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myView = UIView()
    myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    self.view.addSubview(myView)
    myView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // here I'm setting the CenterX & CenterY constraint equal to its superview CenterX & CenterY
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    // here I'm setting the width constraint equal to its superview width
    view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: myView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

    // here I'm setting the aspect ratio constraint to equal width or height of myView
    // since  aspect ratio constraint belongs to self width or height so add this constraints it self(i.e. myView) but not in its superView
    myView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item : myView, attribute: .Width, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: myView, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
yourView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
yourView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: yourView, attribute: .Height, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: yourView, attribute: .Equal, multiplier: 1, constant: yourWidthHere))
```

Or you can drag IBOutlet of your Width Constraint and Height Constraint to your ViewController:

```
@IBOutlet weak var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var widthConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
```

and set the height equal to width:

```
heightConstraint.constant = widthConstraint.constant
```

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this on storyboard?

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to make a constraint equal another constraint through the storyboard, this has to be done in code like the above.